# how to remove element from node__product__type.tpl.php commerce kickstart

Tags: commerce, theming

In my website with commerce kickstart, I would like to remove div with its class name "field_label" in node__product__type.tpl.php. I have no idea of how to code to remove it. Any suggestion is greatly appreciate.

html

```
<div class="field-label">
    tshirt size: 
</div>
```

node__product__type.tpl.php

```
<article<?php print $attributes; ?>>
<?php print "testing product testing" ?>
<?php print $user_picture; ?>
<?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
<?php if (!$page && $title): ?>
  <header>
     <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><a href="<?php print $node_url ?>" title="<?php print $title ?>"><?php print $title ?></a></h2>
  </header>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
<?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
<footer class="submitted"><?php print $date; ?> -- <?php print $name; ?></footer>
  <?php endif; ?>
 <div class="container-24 grid-14 prefix-1 clearfix">
   <?php print render($content['product:field_images']); ?>
 </div>
<div class="container-24 grid-8 prefix-1">
   <div<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
     <?php
      // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
       hide($content['comments']);
       hide($content['links']);
       print render($content);
    ?>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container-24 grid-24 clearfix">
    <?php if (!empty($content['links'])): ?>
    <nav class="links node-links clearfix"><?php print render($content['links']);?></nav>
  <?php endif; ?>
    <?php
      print render($content['comments']);
    ?>
   </div>
 </article>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove both the class and the label, 'tshirt size:', you don't have to do it via code. You can use the "Display settings" of the product and make the label hidden. ie, Go to content type -> Manage Display -> Node and select hidden for the size label.